# Diagonal Hamiltonian of 3 Spin 1/2 Particles

Tags: homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum

I have three Spin 1/2 Particles and a Hamiltonian given by
$$H=A(S_1\cdot S_2)+B(S_2\cdot S_3+S_1\cdot S_3)$$
In order to find the energy spectrum, I want to diagonalize H in terms of $(S_1+S_2+S_3)^2$ and a coupling of 2 of them (I already have spectrum of $H=A(S_1\cdot S_2)$).  However, every combination I have tried if terms of coefficients and couplings have not been successful, so I was hoping someone could give me a hint as to how to couple these guys. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints:

1. Notice that if we define $\mathbf S_{123} = \mathbf S_1 + \mathbf S_2 + \mathbf S_3$ and $\mathbf S_{12} = \mathbf S_1 + \mathbf S_2$, then we have
   \begin{align}
     \mathbf S_{123}^2 = \mathbf S_{12}^2 + \mathbf S_3^2 + 2\mathbf S_{12}\cdot\mathbf S_3
   \end{align}
2. Notice that your hamiltonian can be written as follows:
   \begin{align}
     H = \frac{A}{2}(\mathbf S_{12}^2- \mathbf S_1^2 - \mathbf S_2^2) + B(\mathbf S_{12}\cdot\mathbf S_3)
   \end{align}
3. Combine the last two hints.
4. Recall that the representation theory of the angular momentum algebra (aka addition of angular momentum) tells us that a tensor product of three spin-$1/2$ reprsentations splits into a direction sum as follows:
   \begin{align}
     \tfrac{1}{2}\otimes\tfrac{1}{2}\otimes\tfrac{1}{2} 
   &= (1 \oplus 0)\otimes\tfrac{1}{2} \\
   &= (1\otimes \tfrac{1}{2}) \oplus (0\otimes \tfrac{1}{2}) \\
   &= \underbrace{(\tfrac{3}{2}\oplus\tfrac{1}{2})}_{s_{12}=1, s_3 = \frac{1}{2}}\oplus \underbrace{\tfrac{1}{2}}_{s_{12}=0, s_3=\frac{1}{2}}
   \end{align}
5. (**Addendum**) To clarify some discussion in the comments, the last line in number 4 means that the Hilbert space admits an orthonormal basis of states which I'll label $|s_{123}, s_{12}\rangle$ for which
   \begin{align}
     \mathbf S_{123}^2|s_{123}, m_{123},s_{12}\rangle &= \hbar^2 s_{123}(s_{123}+1)|s_{123}, m_{123},s_{12}\rangle \\
     S_{123}^z |s_{123}, m_{123},s_{12}\rangle &= \hbar m_{123}|s_{123}, m_{123},s_{12}\rangle\\
   \mathbf S_{12}^2|s_{123}, m_{123},s_{12}\rangle &= \hbar^2 s_{12}(s_{12}+1)|s_{123}, m_{123},s_{12}\rangle \\
   \mathbf S_{1}^2|s_{123}, m_{123},s_{12}\rangle &= \hbar^2 \tfrac{1}{2}(\tfrac{1}{2}+1)|s_{123}, m_{123},s_{12}\rangle \\
   \mathbf S_{2}^2|s_{123}, m_{123},s_{12}\rangle &= \hbar^2 \tfrac{1}{2}(\tfrac{1}{2}+1)|s_{123}, m_{123},s_{12}\rangle \\
   \mathbf S_{3}^2|s_{123}, m_{123},s_{12}\rangle &= \hbar^2 \tfrac{1}{2}(\tfrac{1}{2}+1)|s_{123}, m_{123},s_{12}\rangle
   \end{align}
   and explicitly, the basis is as follows:
   \begin{align}
     \left.\begin{array}{l}
       |\tfrac{3}{2}, \tfrac{3}{2},1\rangle \\
       |\tfrac{3}{2}, \tfrac{1}{2},1\rangle \\
       |\tfrac{3}{2}, -\tfrac{1}{2},1\rangle \\
       |\tfrac{3}{2}, -\tfrac{3}{2},1\rangle 
     \end{array}\right\} s_{123} = \tfrac{3}{2}, s_{12} = 1, \dim = 4\\
     \left.\begin{array}{l}
       |\tfrac{1}{2}, \tfrac{1}{2},1\rangle \\
       |\tfrac{1}{2}, -\tfrac{1}{2},1\rangle
     \end{array}\right\} s_{123} = \tfrac{1}{2}, s_{12} = 1, \dim = 2\\
     \left.\begin{array}{l}
       |\tfrac{1}{2}, \tfrac{1}{2},0\rangle \\
       |\tfrac{1}{2}, -\tfrac{1}{2},0\rangle
     \end{array}\right\} s_{123} = \tfrac{1}{2}, s_{12} = 0, \dim = 2
   \end{align}
   This is a basis for the entire three spin-$1/2$ particle Hilbert space; it is eight-dimensional.  There are therefore a total of 8 orthonormal eigenvectors for the hamiltonian.

Comment: You are actually the best.  As a followup, from yesterday, I know the spectrum of $S_{12}$ and then $S_{123}$ can be 3/2 or 1/2?

Comment: Haha ;).  Yup, I think you got it.  Basically the last line of 4 is saying that the Hilbert space decomposes into orthogonal subspaces, two of which have total spin quantum number $s_{123} = \tfrac{1}{2}$ and one of which has $s_{123} = \tfrac{3}{2}$, and within each of these subspaces, $s_{12}$ has a certain value based on where that subspace came from when we first combined the first and second spins.

Comment: For degeneracies, I know that I can have 4 $S_{123}=3/2$ states, and that would be coupled with 3 $S_{12}=1$ states and just one $S_{12}=0$ state.  Same goes for $S_{123}=1/2$, except I only have two possible states for that to coupled with $S_{12}$?

Comment: If I do that, I only get 24 states.  Shouldn't I have 27?

Comment: @yankeefan11 I don't quite follow.  The spin-$\frac{1}{2}$ Hilbert space is $2$-dimensional, so its threefold tensor product has dimension $2^3 = 8$.  This matches the dimension of the direct sum since $\dim(\frac{3}{2}\oplus\frac{1}{2}\oplus\frac{1}{2}) = 4 + 2 + 2 = 8$.

Comment: So when I do that out, I have four energies, and 24 states.

Comment: @yankeefan11 Are you somehow attempting to multiply by $3$ after counting the $8$ states I mentioned above?  You shouldn't; I was counting the total number of dimensions of the entire Hilbert space, namely $8$.  When I used an underbrace and labeled the value of $s_{12}$ in the answer, this was only to indicate that in the underbraced subspace, that would be the value of $s_{12}$.

Comment: No, so I have that I have 4 possible states of $S_{123},S_{12}$.  For $S_{123}=3/2$ there are 4 possible.  If I have $S_{123}$ with $S_{12}=1$, $S_{12}$ has 3 possible states.  I get that the energy is $\hbar^2/4 (A+2B)$ with degeneracy 12.

Comment: @yankeefan11 See the addendum I just wrote.

Comment: How can I figure out the degeneracies of these?

Comment: @yankeefan11 Degeneracy refers to the number of eigenstates corresponding to a given energy.  Figure out the energies of the eight states, then group them together according to which ones have the same energy.  The size of each group is the degeneracy of that energy eigenvalue.

Comment: I only find three energies. And I also notice that you had 3 combinations of $S_{123},S_{12}$

Comment: With respective degeneracies 12,6,2.  This is built off the fact that in your addundum, for each $|S_{123},m_{123},S_{12}\rangle$ there are either three projections of $S_{12}$ or just 1 ($=0$)

Comment: @yankeefan11 Almost.  There are three energies, with degeneracies $4,2,2$.  The $s_{123} = 3/2$ subspace has a certain energy, and is four-dimensional (there are 4 corresponding states), and the two $s_{123}=1/2$ subspaces each have a certain energy, and each is $2$-dimensional (there are two corresponding states for each).

Comment: So am I correct in saying that for the initial Hamiltonian, there are three possible energies with degeneracy 4,2,2

Comment: @yankeefan11 Yes.